# Among investment histories how to find the cumulative sum option that proves to be more reliable for the long term?

Tags: python, pandas, standard-deviation, cumsum

In fact, not always the chart that reaches the highest peak of positive value when doing cumulative sum is the most reliable for long-term investments, because a single investment may have generated a very high profit but then it returns to the normal of being negative and if become an endless fall.

Also relying on higher ROI (return on investment) is risky for the same reasons as above.

That said, the cumulative sum graphs generated by these test values are:

```python
ex_csv_1 = """
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,return
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,-1
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,-1
a,b,c,1
"""
```

[image]

```python
ex_csv_2 = """
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,return
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,-2
a,b,c,-3
a,b,c,4
a,b,c,5
a,b,c,6
a,b,c,7
"""
```

[image]

```python
ex_csv_3 = """
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,return
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,-2
a,b,c,2
"""
```

[image]

If I wanted to find the one with the biggest peak, I would do it this way:

```python
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import io

ex_csv_1 = """
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,return
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,-1
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,-1
a,b,c,1
"""

ex_csv_2 = """
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,return
a,b,c,1
a,b,c,-2
a,b,c,-3
a,b,c,4
a,b,c,5
a,b,c,6
a,b,c,7
"""

ex_csv_3 = """
Col 1,Col 2,Col 3,return
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,2
a,b,c,-2
a,b,c,2
"""

def save_fig(cs):
    values = np.cumsum(cs[2])
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(values)
    fig.savefig(f'a_graph.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
    fig.clf()
    plt.close('all')

options = []

for i,strio in enumerate([ex_csv_1,ex_csv_2,ex_csv_3]):
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(strio), sep=",")
    df['invest'] = df.groupby(['Col 1','Col 2','Col 3'])['return'].cumsum().gt(df['return'])
    pl = df[(df['invest'] == True)]['return']
    total_sum = pl.sum()
    roi = total_sum/len(pl)
    options.append([total_sum,roi,pl])
max_list = max(options, key=lambda sublist: sublist[0])
save_fig(max_list)
```

But how should I go about finding which track record among the three demonstrates keeping the smallest fluctuation and delivering the greatest long-term reliability?

I will put two charts below, the second chart that has less oscillations is the most reliable among them for the long term, as the variations are smaller and maintains a crescent with an established pattern:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for a clear set of dataframes to work from! However, I don't understand the target solution. Could you define "smallest fluctuation" more clearly? One possible solution is to perform a linear regression on each of the three datasets and choose one which has a high R-value (small fluctuation) and a high slope (increasing over time).

Comment: Hi @SNygard thanks for support, These three examples would be like three investment histories made and I'm trying to figure out which history would be the one that proves to be more reliable for me to continue investing. Because just looking at the graph that reached the highest point, there is the risk that I mentioned of having been a single investment that was very positive but the rest negative, so in the long term the chance of being a loss is greater than the one that has a smaller variation but it rises and maintains a pattern.

Comment: I think this question might be better suited on https://money.stackexchange.com to clarify the logic that works best for this application. Once you have clearly defined the logic, then we can help you write that into code.

Comment: @SNygard I added at the end of the question a comparison of two charts where clearly one demonstrates a pretty reliable pattern compared to the other.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple measure of "reliability" in a graph is how well the graph matches with linear behavior. To calculate this, we can perform a linear regression on the data. The `scipy.stats` package has a nice built-in function for this. A "good" result should have a high R-value, meaning the data are behaving linearly. Also, the slope of the result should be positive, meaning it increases over time.

```
results = {}
for i,strio in enumerate([ex_csv_1,ex_csv_2,ex_csv_3]):
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(strio), sep=",")
    df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['Col 1','Col 2','Col 3'])['return'].cumsum()

    # Perform the linear regression
    linreg = scipy.stats.linregress(df.index,df['cumsum'])

    # Save the results for comparison later
    results[i] = linreg

    # Plot to see how the regression matches the data
    plt.plot(df.index, df['cumsum'])
    xmin, xmax = min(df.index), max(df.index)
    plt.plot(
        [xmin, xmax], 
        [xmin*linreg.slope + linreg.intercept, xmax*linreg.slope + linreg.intercept],
        label = "slope: {:g}\nR-value:{:g}".format(linreg.slope, linreg.rvalue)
    )
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
results
```

The output `results` are:

```
{0: LinregressResult(slope=0.2857142857142857, intercept=1.1428571428571428, rvalue=0.7559289460184545, pvalue=0.04931308767365261, stderr=0.11065666703449761),
 1: LinregressResult(slope=3.0, intercept=-4.714285714285714, rvalue=0.8373248339703451, pvalue=0.01874218974109145, stderr=0.8759834123860507),
 2: LinregressResult(slope=1.2857142857142856, intercept=3.0, rvalue=0.9185586535436918, pvalue=0.0034781651152865026, stderr=0.24743582965269673)}
```

I would interpret this as:

1. Low R-Value: Plot one has a lot of variability. Low slope: bad return on investment
2. OK  R-Value: Plot is more consistent. High slope: good return on investment
3. High R-Value: Plot is very consistent. High slope: good return on investment

Comment: also I would add the difference between the linear regression and the value itself, as a percentage. In the end, I calculated this average value. The smaller this value would be, the lower the volatility (theoretically, the drawdown of the balance).

Comment: Hi @inquirer I was curious to better understand how you decided to do the calculation to arrive at the final result of which of the three models would currently be the best, if possible, share from an answer so that I and other people in the future have the complete vision of your method.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer 1. We build a regression line (the slope must be positive, that is, the first value is less than the last). 2. We calculate the correlation of values with the regression line, the larger it is, the better it should ideally be equal to 1. 3. We take the absolute difference between the values and the regression values in percent (value - regression) / (regression / 100). We calculate the average of these values (the smaller it is, the better. That is, less volatility, balance drawdown). In ascending order of importance: slope, correlation coefficient, difference.

Comment: Hi @inquirer I have not been able to reproduce this indicated process, if you are interested in sharing in an answer so that I and others can see in the future, it would be of great value. Anyway, thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Used a similar approach as suggested by SNygard with some additions to what i said earlier. As data I took several segments of the 'MA' stock, closing prices act as your 'return' data here. If you want to use your data, then uncomment the following row: `x['invest'] = x['return'].cumsum()` and replace `'Close'` with `'invest'` everywhere.

df = dataframe number, coef = slope, R = correlation coefficient between values and regression line, dif = absolute percentage difference.

With a difference in percentage, everything turned out to be not so clear. The first dataframe has a low value, but the fourth also has a low value, but a small correlation coefficient. I think it should be used in conjunction. By its value, you can see the hypothetical possible drawdown of the balance as a percentage.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import yfinance as yf

# """
df1 = yf.download('MA', start='2019-01-05', end='2019-04-23').reset_index()
df2 = yf.download('MA', start="2018-01-01", end="2018-04-21").reset_index()
df3 = yf.download('MA', start="2020-02-01", end="2020-05-21").reset_index()
df4 = yf.download('MA', start='2017-01-05', end='2017-04-23').reset_index()

df = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
hist = len(df)

aaa = np.ones((hist, 4), dtype=float)

for ind, x in enumerate(df):
    lr = LinearRegression()
    index = x.index.values.reshape((-1, 1))
    #x['invest'] = x['return'].cumsum()
    lr.fit(index, x['Close'])
    x['lr'] = lr.predict(index)
    x['dif'] = np.abs((x['Close'] - x['lr'])/(x['lr']/100.0))
    R = lr.score(index, x['Close'])
    aaa[ind][0] = ind
    aaa[ind][1] = lr.coef_
    aaa[ind][2] = R
    aaa[ind][3] = x['dif'].mean()

rows = int(hist / 2)
if hist % 2 > 0:
    rows += 1

for i in range(0, hist):
    ax = plt.subplot(rows, 2, i + 1)
    ur = df[i]['Close'].min() + (df[i]['Close'].max() - df[i]['Close'].min()) / 10
    ax.text(df[i].index[-40], ur, 'df =' + str(int(aaa[i][0]) + 1) + ',' + ' coef='
            + str(round(aaa[i][1], 2)) + ' R=' + str(round(aaa[i][2],2))
            + ' dif = ' + str(round(aaa[i][3],2)), fontsize=10, ha='center')

    ax.plot(df[i].index, df[i]['Close'])
    ax.plot(df[i].index, df[i]['lr'])

plt.show()
```

[image]
if you want to see the difference separately:

```
for i in range(0, hist):
    ax = plt.subplot(rows, 2, i + 1)
    ur = df[i]['dif'].min() + (df[i]['dif'].max() - df[i]['dif'].min()) / 10
    ax.text(df[i].index[-40], ur, 'df =' + str(int(aaa[i][0]) + 1) + ',' + ' coef='
            + str(round(aaa[i][1], 2)) + ' R=' + str(round(aaa[i][2], 2))
            + ' dif = ' + str(round(aaa[i][3], 2)), fontsize=10, ha='center')

    ax.plot(df[i].index, df[i]['dif'])

plt.show()
```

or get the best dataframe by correlation coefficient:

```
aaa = aaa[aaa[:, 1] > 0]
aaa = aaa[(-aaa[:, 2]).argsort()]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df[int(aaa[0][0])].index, df[int(aaa[0][0])]['Close'])
ax.plot(df[int(aaa[0][0])].index, df[int(aaa[0][0])]['lr'])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will readjust for my case and any additional questions I will leave in the comments. Thank you in advance for your time and help so far, I know it will help me a lot with new approaches and additional understandings!

Comment: Notice the **pvalue** in SNygard's suggestion. Perhaps this will help too.

Comment: Yes yes, I am collating the information. Because whenever my code find a new opportunity, my code before indicating the investment, it must find which historical model of current investment is the most reliable and only after that it will analyze whether the new opportunity fits the requirements of that model.

Comment: From practice, it happens that a good value of the correlation coefficient, but large drawdowns and this needs to be handled somehow. Are you into algorithmic trading?